# Получить следующие N значения и записать в строку

Tags: php, foreach

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу. Нужно обработать большой прайс в XLS, переписать его и сохранить в CSV. Основная задача решена, кроме как не могу получить определенные данные.

Сейчас получаю данные такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
foreach( $stock as $k => $s ) {
  $sku = $s[5]; // артикул
  
  if (!empty($s[2])) {
    $names = $s[2];
  } else {
    $names = '';
  }
  
  if (!empty($s[4])) {
    $color = $s[4];
  } else {
    $color = '';
  }
   
  if (!empty($s[5])) {
    if (!empty($s[10]) && !empty($s[3])) {
      if (empty($stock[$k+1][2]) && !empty($stock[$k+1][17])) {
        
        $checksum = crc32($sku);
        
        //variable product
        $parrent_product = array(
          'variable', // тип
          $checksum, // артикул
          '', // Родительский ID
          $names, // Имя
          '',
          '', //Цвет
        );
        fputcsv($fp, $parrent_product);
        
        //first variation
        $row = array(
          'variation', // тип
          $sku, // артикул
          $checksum, // Родительский ID
          '', // Имя
          'Цвет',
          $color, //Цвет
        );
      } else {
        //simple product
        $row = array(
          'simple', // тип
          $sku, // артикул
          '', // Родительский ID
          $names, // Имя
          '',
          '', //Цвет
        );
      }
    } else if (!empty($s[17])) {
      //variation product
      $row = array(
        'variation', // тип
        $sku, // артикул
        $checksum, // Родительский ID
        '', // Имя
        'Цвет',
        $color, //Цвет
      );
    }
  }
  fputcsv($fp, $row); // записываем в CSV
}
```

Необходимо в тип **Variable** в столбец Значение атрибутов 1 добавить через запятую значения всех дочерних элементов ниже, до нового товара типа Simple или Variable. Чтобы получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно получить значения товаров ниже? Спасибо.

Comment: накапливайте в массив до следующего непустого name, а потом дополнительным циклом разружайте

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, можно пожалуйста пример. Уже просто несколько вариантов пробовал, не получается. Получилось еще одним циклом вытащить значения, но он в строку записывает все значения всех цветов. Т.е. не останавливается

Comment: Лайфхак: обьявите константы `define("COLUMN_SKU", 5)`, а потом вместо `$s[5]` пишите `$s[COLUMN_SKU]` - так будет намного проще понимать какой столбец вы используете, а при смене порядка столбцов - легко исправить скрипт =)

Comment: Так же для пустых переменных можете использовать короткий тернарный оператор `?:`: `$names = $s[2] ?: "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо сначала сформировать весь массив целиком, добавляя цвета в variable и потом только записывать в файл

```
<?php
$row=array();
foreach ($stock as $k => $s)
{
    $sku = $s[5]; // артикул

    if (!empty($s[2]))
    {
        $names = $s[2];
    }
    else
    {
        $names = '';
    }
    
    if (!empty($s[4]))
    {
        $color = $s[4];
    }
    else
    {
        $color = '';
    }
    
    if (!empty($s[5]))
    {
        if (!empty($s[10]) && !empty($s[3]))
        {
            if (empty($stock[$k + 1][2]) && !empty($stock[$k + 1][17]))
            {
                $checksum = crc32($sku);
                
                //variable product
                $parrent_product = array(
                    'variable', // тип
                    $checksum, // артикул
                    '', // Родительский ID
                    $names, // Имя
                    '',
                    '' //Цвет
                );
//              fputcsv($fp, $parrent_product);
$row[]=$parrent_product;
$parrent_product_id=count($row)-1;  // запоминаем индекс строчки     variable           

                //first variation
                $row[] = array(
                    'variation', // тип
                    $sku, // артикул
                    $checksum, // Родительский ID
                    '', // Имя
                    'Цвет',
                    $color //Цвет
                );
$row[$parrent_product_id][5]=$color; // добавляем в наш variable первый цвет
            }
            else
            {
                //simple product
                $row[] = array(
                    'simple', // тип
                    $sku, // артикул
                    '', // Родительский ID
                    $names, // Имя
                    '',
                    '' //Цвет
                );
            }
        }
        else if (!empty($s[17]))
        {
            //variation product
            $row[] = array(
                'variation', // тип
                $sku, // артикул
                $checksum, // Родительский ID
                '', // Имя
                'Цвет',
                $color //Цвет
            );
$row[$parrent_product_id][5]=$row[$parrent_product_id][5].','.$color; // добавляем     в наш variable остальные цвета через запятую
        }
    }
//  fputcsv($fp, $row); // записываем в CSV
}

foreach ($row as $fields)     // записываем в файл сформированный массив
 {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Все отлично работает.